# Solving a matrix with $A^n$

Tags: matrices

I have a given Matrix

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 3 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
I have to find $A^2$ and $A^3$, I understand that this is just matrix multiplication, so for $A^2$ I got

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 6\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

With $A^3$ I am a bit confused with how many columns and rows I will have in the end, I am looking for steps to complete it, I understand it will just be the original times itself 3 times, but would it still be a $3\times 3$ matrix?

Comment: Wouldn't it be the zero matrix?

Comment: $A^3=A^2 \times A$.  Since both matrices on the right are $3x3$, so will the answer.

Comment: A square matrix to any power has the same dimensions

Comment: The product of two square matrices of the same size is a square matrix of the same size.

Answer (score 3):

$A^3=A^2A=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 6\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 3 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$